# Error: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$browser.cookies()')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am using Karma and Jasmine to run unit tests on the angular modules within my app. I'm running into an issue where using httpBackend.flush(); is throwing the error in the title. I've researched it best I can and I can only find issues with different angular/mocks versions.

My versions are as follows:

- Angular - 1.3.16
- Angular Mocks - ^1.3.15
- PhantomJS - ^1.9.17

Is it really that specific that the version numbers be exact?

Here is my test:

```
it('it returns address search results properly.', function() {

    $httpBackend.when('GET', strTestAddressApiURL).respond(httpResponse_AddressResults);

    $scope.firstname = 'Jon';
    $scope.lastname = 'Watson';
    $scope.street = '102 2nd Ave';
    $scope.postalcode = '81144';
    $scope.findBy = 'address';

    $scope.submit(true);
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect($scope.data[0].accountnumber).toBe('2422101405');
    expect($scope.data[0].firstname).toBe('Jon');
    expect($scope.data[0].lastname).toBe('Watson');
    expect($scope.data[0].email).toBe('jwatson@fh.org');
    expect($scope.data[0].address).toBe('102 2nd Ave');
    expect($scope.data[0].postalcode).toBe('81144');

    expect($scope.data[1].accountnumber).toBe('2422113499');
    expect($scope.data[1].firstname).toBe('Joan');
    expect($scope.data[1].lastname).toBe('Watson');
    expect($scope.data[1].email).toBe('joan@fh.org');
    expect($scope.data[1].address).toBe('102 2nd Ave');
    expect($scope.data[1].postalcode).toBe('81144');

});
```

Here is $scope.submit from the controller

```
$scope.submit = function(isValid) {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            if(!isValid) {
                return;
            } else {
                if($scope.findBy == 'email') {
                    var validEmail = RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}');
                    if(!validEmail.test($scope.email)) {
                        $scope.findaccount.email.$invalid = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Show `$scope.submit`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan updated :-)

Comment: So, where is the actual `$http` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - it was infact the version numbers being off even the slightest bit.